# Migrate multiple same databases in propel

Tags: php, symfony, multilingual, propel, database-migration

I have a multilingual application with each language data in a separate database. This is how it’s configured in Symfony 2.2 and Propel 1.6 (excerpt from config key `propel.dbal.connections`):

```
pl_general: &GENERAL
    <<: *BASEDB
    dsn:        mysql:host=%db_host%;dbname=%db_general%_pl%db_suffix%
general:
    <<: *GENERAL
ar_general:
    <<: *BASEDB
    dsn:        mysql:host=%db_host%;dbname=%db_general%_ar%db_suffix%
at_general:
    <<: *BASEDB
    dsn:        mysql:host=%db_host%;dbname=%db_general%_at%db_suffix%
bg_general:
    <<: *BASEDB
    dsn:        mysql:host=%db_host%;dbname=%db_general%_bg%db_suffix%
```

And so on. There is one `general` connection that points to my default language. All other databases have the exact same structure as my default. I have a `general-schema.xml` with all models configured.

The problem begins when I try to generate a diff (`propel:migration:generate-diff`) or execute a migration (`propel:migration:migrate`). Propel does not know that those connections are siblings, and anything relating to the `general` connection should also be executed on every `LANG_general` connection.  Also, when doing a diff, only the default db is compared against the schema/models, so I cannot guarantee the integrity.

I would like to:

- make sure that all of the databases have the same structure
- add all new changes to a group of connections at once and without much hassle

I’m looking for a by-the-book solution, preferably using Propel own mechanisms, but I am open to all suggestions. Whatever works and is stable. Opinions, comments and proven solutions very welcome! Source code appreciated

Comment: Would it perhaps be easier to have all of your language tables in the same database?

Comment: I think it would get worse. Generated migration would have `Alter table user` -- no way I could easily apply this to `user_en`, `user_fr`, `user_es`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What have I figured so far:

- One can wrap the `generate-diff` command in their own and alter the migration class to copy all the SQL statements across all of my connections, i.e. turn this:

  ```
  return [
    'general' => '/** STATEMENTS **/'
  ];
  ```

  Into this:

  ```
  return [
    'pl_general' => '/** STATEMENTS **/',
    'at_general' => '/** STATEMENTS **/',
    'ar_general' => '/** STATEMENTS **/',
    'bg_general' => '/** STATEMENTS **/',
  ];
  ```

  This is a bit of hacking and is only good as long as the migration classes format does not change.
- One can apply all the migrations in a loop for every connection, changing the name each time, i.e. bind `LANG_general` as `general`. I’m not sure about the consequences.
- One could alter the schema/process somehow, so that any `LANG_general` would match to `general` schema — for example by copying all the schema files before the process. The `diff` and `migrate` commands would operate on each connections separately, but with the same results. This would be also more time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with Propel 1.7.x migrations recently, and strangely what I regard as an anti-feature may be very useful in your case. If you add a `buildtime-conf.xml` file (using the same format as your `runtime-conf.xml`) then you can add multiple connections that will get migrated in one go.

You'd need to ensure that a `propel_migration` table is created for each of these, so they are treated separately.

As I've outlined [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375703/what-does-a-good-practice-propel-migrations-workflow-look-like), I think it would have made more sense for the developer to specify *which* connection gets migrated (thus allowing migrations on a per-environment basis).

It will be interesting to see how this is implemented for Propel2 (and if you have any thoughts on the matter, now is a good time to raise a ticket: it is currently in alpha, with a beta some way off).