# What does a good-practice Propel migrations workflow look like?

Tags: php, database-migration, propel

I'm new to Propel ORM migrations, and to migrations in general, and am interested in how a dev and deploy workflow can work with this library in particular. I have the master of the current stable (1.7.x) in mind, as there are some technical restrictions that in my view would shape the workflow people choose (the situation may be different in Propel 2).

I'm working on a new product for which I expect to have four environments: test, local, staging and live. These are defined in `runtime-conf.xml` as one would expect. Before today, I was making database changes by running the commands `om` (generate classes), `sql` (generate SQL), `insert-sql` (init database). Of course that wipes everything, so I have now switched to migrations: `diff` to generate change classes, `migrate` to apply all pending migrations in order.

Now, if you have just one build connection, you can use `build.properties`. However, I (will) have four, and they will have different hostnames and passwords. The [Migration docs](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/10-migrations.html) weren't much help when Propel complained I didn't have a `buildtime-conf.xml`, but there is a brief note [hidden elsewhere](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/buildtime-configuration.html#database-settings) to describe the format of this. So I added that, only to find that multiple connections are *all* migrated (rather than using a specified one, as is the case with run-time connections).

I have thus used the Phing console options to specify one of several build-time files, which feels like a bit of a kludge (although I later found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27567579/472495) suggesting the same thing). Is this how folks are generally doing migrations on a per-connection basis?

I'm also concerned about the potential increasing number of the migration classes. When doing a deploy, this could run to hundreds of changes, making a new build slower that it needs to be. A frozen set of generated SQL files are required as well, so I guess once migration is set up, these files should not be regenerated?

Is it good practice to periodically refresh the generated SQL file(s) to a known point and delete some migrations accordingly, or is the reassurance of a full set of working migrations (for nearly a whole development history) worth it for a slower deployment?

Lastly, migrations feel a bit brittle for me at the moment, since the partial failure of one can leave the database in a half-way house state. Is a staging database a good enough mitigation for this (i.e. run the migrations on staging, and if they work there, it's good enough for live)?

Comment: I stand corrected but I don't think you'd want to run build commands in staging and production.  Ideally you only need one(1) environment to do all the builds and migrations (once), after which you would then distribute your class changes to other through a version control system to distribute to other environments, as well as running your SQL migrations code (from the migration class) against each environment's database.  Additionally it is always recommended to review the migration class before running it.

Comment: @Qiniso: thanks. For the benefit of other readers, who may be confused, I think your comment is a reply to a comment I made to you [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27567579/472495). Yes, nothing I've written here is intended to suggest that migration classes need to be built outside of the local environment. Meanwhile, if you have any thoughts based on your experience of the migration workflow as it applies to Propel, please do share.

Comment: (Since writing this post I've more experience with migrations, and I have a workflow that I'm fairly happy with, and I think it is as least an improvement on deploying database changes manually using SQL scripts. When I get a moment I will write an answer to summarise some of the things I've learned).

Comment: I think i got interrupted while replying... I'm not even sure what I was going to say more than "test, verify, test, verify, repeat till you stop cringing at running it on staging or prod".

Comment: @prodigitalson, heh, righto. My solution is to build it into my unit tests: the PHPUnit bootstrap builds a database from a frozen SQL file, then runs each committed migration in turn, including any customisations I've made to the migration class (e.g. adding new records). This seems to test it quite thoroughly.

Comment: Part of my current thoughts on this [are contained in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28671466/472495). There's probably more detail to add, so at some point I'll write an answer here too.

Comment: I think the other answer stands as a good enough answer to this question, so I'll vote to close this.